# XSLT input parameter not picked up when Saxon is in use?

Tags: java, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am passing a simple string parameter to my Saxon-driven XSLT, but it is not getting picked up.

Here's the XSL (`min.xsl`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:param name="in"/>
        <Out>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Val = $in">match!</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Val"/> != <xsl:value-of select="$in"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Out>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the code used to invoke the XSLT:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class MinXSLT {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
            System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
            System.out.println("Plugged in Saxon");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignore) {}

        final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer e = transformerFactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/min.xsl"))).newTransformer();
        e.setParameter("in", "x");
        e.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<Val>x</Val>")), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }
}
```

Here's the `dependencies` section of my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon-he</artifactId>
        <version>9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Yup, just `saxon-he`.

Strangely, when I remove the Saxon dependency, the parameter gets picked up and I get the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Out>match!</Out>
```

But when Saxon is in use, I get the 'parameter mismatch' result with an empty string in place of the parameter value:

```
Plugged in Saxon
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Out>x != </Out>
```

What is my crime here?

For the record, I tried using newer versions of Saxon (`net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:9.7.x` etc.), with the same result; however in the actual project I am stuck with `saxon:saxon-he:9.2` so upgrading is not really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `<xsl:param name="in"/>` outside of any `xsl:template` to have it as a global parameter you can set before the transformation. `xsl:param`s inside templates are not settable by the JAXP transformation API, in XSLT 3 with Saxon's API you could call a named template or function directly and set its parameters when doing so but your approach with applying templates to a Source in JAXP is not meant for that. Simply use a global parameter, i.e. move the `xsl:param` outside of any `xsl:template` and make it a child of `xsl:stylesheet/xsl:transform`.

Comment: It has always been my understanding too that JAXP Transformer.setParameter() could only be used to set a global `xsl:param` in the stylesheet. However, the JAXP documentation is so far removed from anything specific to XSLT that other interpretations are possible, and it looks as if other vendors have indeed interpreted it differently. There's unfortunately a long history of JAXP interoperability problems caused by fuzziness in the specification.

Comment: Although JAXP documentation is fuzzy, I think the XSLT 1.0 spec is reasonably clear in its intent: §11.4 "A top-level xsl:param element declares a parameter to the stylesheet; XSLT does not define the mechanism by which parameters are passed to the stylesheet. ", §11.6 "Parameters are passed to templates using the xsl:with-param element."

Comment: And XSLT 2.0 is prescriptive about it: §2.3 "Parameters passed to the transformation by the client application are matched against stylesheet parameters (see 9.5 Global Variables and Parameters), not against the template parameters declared within the initial template. All template parameters within the initial template to be executed will take their default values.
"

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Any idea why the original (non-global) `xsl:param` works in the absence of Saxon (in which case I believe `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` shipped with the JDK - 1.7 in my case - would be in charge)? Is it some non-standard behaviour of the default implementation?

Comment: @JanakaBandara, I am not sure about Xalan, whether the version internalized in the JRE/JDK or the standalone release from Apache, I would need to test that separately when I am at a deskop set up to do Java development, but so far when using APIs to XSLT 1 processors I have always considered any `setParameter` or similar method to be dedicated to set global parameters, never to set those local to templates. So my understanding and reasoning is much along the lines Michael Kay outlined in his comments and excepts from the XSLT specs.